# Popout window in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Basic question: how do I open a new window with a button?

Comment: You'll need to add a little more information.  Do you mean in a browser?  Or Winforms?  What have you tried already?

Comment: look the answers question is not clear but... :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I missed your tag asp.net, in ASP.NET, if you want to create a button, we will use javascript

```
<input type="button" value="Open New Window" onclick="window.open('newpage.html')">
```

if you want to create a hyperlink with same purpose, you will create a hyperlink with **target='_blank'** for example

```
<a href='newpage.aspx' target='_blank'>Open new window</a>
```

and

For windows forms, if you have another forms called Form2, you use

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
```

if you want it to show as a new separate form, then you call

```
form2.Show();
```

if you want it to appear as a dialog box, then you call

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

More discussion over here, Modal vs Modaless window
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

you have for example two forms... form1 and form2... form1 has a button1

in the button1 event handler (double click the button to create it) just type in

```
form2 f = new form2();
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are implying windows Form:

Create an instance of the Form and call the `Show()` method.

For example

```
private void btnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 MyformType myForm = new MyformType();
myForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: @Govind: Oh I see. I guess the question wasn't clear. If he corrects it, I would need to consider editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the asp.net tag there, so to do that, u need to use javascript.
Try a simple script like

```
Response.Write("<script language='Javascript'>alert('Test')</script>");
```

Put it in the event handler of your button and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a serverside button, you can use the following, assuming you have a button named Button1 and want to open a window going to www.microsoft.com

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('www.microsoft.com'); return false;");
```

Put that code in the Page_Load event (for example).
The `return false;` prevents a postback from occuring when you click the button.

If you want it simply using HTML controls then you can do the following (credit to [Cherhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441149/cherhan)):

```
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="window.open('www.microsoft.com')">
```